# TYPO3 12.4 sf_register - Extend fields to all fe_user fields (e.g., www, name, ...)

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

Is there any way to add all fe_user fields (e.g., www, name, ...) to be able to be selected as input for the registration-edit user form?

Currently, there is a long list of items (e.g., username, pseudonym, ..) but some fields of fe_user are missing.

[image: Plugin Options, "www" missing in the list of Available Items]

Comment: Seems, you "just" need to extend the configuration: https://docs.typo3.org/p/evoweb/sf-register/12.0/en-us/Extendability/Index.html